# What does $2^H$ mean, where H is finite group?

Tags: notation, finite-groups

From Henry Cohn [paper](http://users.cms.caltech.edu/~umans/papers/CKSU05.pdf):

Definition 6.5. Let $H$ be a finite abelian group. An $H$-
chart $\mathcal{C} = (Γ, A, B, C)$ consists of a finite set of symbols $Γ$,
together with three mappings $A, B, C: \Gamma \to 2^H$ such that
: $Γ$ for each $x ∈ Γ$, the sets $A(x), B(x), C(x)$ satisfy the triple
product property. Let $\mathcal{H}(\mathcal{C}) ⊆ Γ^3$ denote the set of ordered
triples $(x, y, z)$ such that
$$0 ∈ A(x) − A(y) + B(y) − B(z) + C(z) − C(x).$$

What does $2^H$ mean, where H is finite group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the set of functions from $H$ to $2 = \{0,1\}$. This can be identified with the set of subsets of $H$ via the map $1_A \mapsto A$ where $1_A$ denotes the characteristic function of $A \subseteq H$.

There's nothing special about $H$ being a group here.

Answer (score 1):

If $S$ is a set, then $2^S$ denotes the set of all subsets of $S$.